# Create a Random AES Key in JS that can transferred to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, aes, rsa

I have a form processing script that uses AES and RSA Encryption together.

At first, I solely used RSA but because of the data limit, I have started using AES encryption whose keys are now encrypted with RSA.

I have made sure that I can decrypt the AES if I generate a random string by hand but when I use

```
var key = forge.random.getBytesSync(32);
var iv = forge.random.getBytesSync(32);
```

I can not transfer it to PHP. When I used PHPAES library, an exception is thrown, complaining that my key size is incorrect.

How can I create Cryptographically Secure Keys that I can also transfer into PHP?

If any more information is needed, I am eager to provide it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The most easy way to transport a random key/iv is to **Base64 encode** the data to sender side and **Base64 decode** the data on recipient side. The encoded form is a string that easily can transported (e.g. via Email).

Comment: There is an issue with your iv - the iv for AES has to been 16 bytes long and not 32 bytes length.

Comment: @Topaco RSA decryption is made beforehand.

Comment: @MichaelFehr that might be the issue because I have already tried base64, and it still complained so that might fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to @MichaelFehr,

I have fixed it. The problem was with the length of the IV.

```
var key = forge.random.getBytesSync(32);
var iv = forge.random.getBytesSync(16); // not 32
```

This works!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I forgot to change it after seeing it work.